# Thread tries to read from or write to virtual address python QtSql

Tags: python, sql-server, qtsql

I have two issues - first off (and more importantly) the second time the code is run from the QGIS Python it fails with "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access".

The second issue is that if I close and remove the database the table displayed using projectView.show() is empty yet if I comment those lines out, the data displays correctly.

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.gui import *

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QODBC')
if db.isValid():
   db.setDatabaseName('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;'
                    % ('ServerName',
                      'Database',
                       'username',
                       'password'))   

    #print "db.isValid"

    if db.open():
        #print "success"
        query = db.exec_("""SELECT TOP 100 postal_address as address, EASTING as x, NORTHING as y FROM dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS WHERE postal_address LIKE('%EX3 %')""")

        projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
        projectModel.setQuery(query)
        projectView = QTableView()
        projectView.setModel(projectModel)

        projectView.show()    

        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Info", "hello")

        query = db.exec_("""SELECT TOP 100 postal_address as address, EASTING as x, NORTHING as y FROM dbo.POSTAL_ADDRESS WHERE postal_address LIKE('%EX2 %')""")

        projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
        projectModel.setQuery(query)
        projectView = QTableView()
        projectView.setModel(projectModel)

        projectView.show()    

        #db.close()
        #db.removeDatabase('QODBC')       

    else:
        QMessageBox.warning(None, "Info", "Error")
 else:
    QMessageBox.warning(None, "Info", "Error")
```

Comment: Is that error a message from a segfault or Windows crash, or is it an exception from Python? If it's an exception, please post the whole traceback, not just the error string.

Comment: I've figured out that it is occurs when query = db.exec_ runs

Comment: Dump Summary
------------
Dump File: qgis-20141218-083144-1364-7108-exported.dmp : C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20141218-083144-1364-7108-exported.dmp
Last Write Time: 18/12/2014 08:31:44
Process Name: qgis-bin.exe : C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\bin\qgis-bin.exe
Process Architecture: x64
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information: Not Present

Comment: You call `db.exec_` twice; which one is crashing?

Comment: Meanwhile, since it seems likely that there's something wrong with your Qt/PyQt/QODBC setup (normally, nothing you write in Python should actually crash, unless you're using `ctypes` or the like), how did you install everything?

Comment: When the file is run in the QGIS python console the first time, both db.exec_ calls work correctly. When the file is run for the second time, that's when the crash occurs. I will ask about the install as our GIS team did that. Could it be an x32 / x64 error? The code I was trying to change originally (same error) worked fine but was connecting to a postgis database but now I'm trying to connect to a sql server db....